# jQuery Mobile dynamic layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What I'm attempting is to replicate the layout on the jQuery Mobile docs pages:

example here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

In particular that when the browser is over a certain width the nav is visible and on the left hand side, but when less than a certain width the nav is shoved below the content.

Now I know I could code this up in javascript, but I was wondering if this is something that either jQuery or jQuery Mobile is giving for free.

I've been trawling through the js and css for that page, but I can't seem to find it.

Any help or suggestions would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually achieved using CSS.

Take a look at their stylesheet :

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css

And search for "content-primary", which is the ID of the menu you are talking about. It has a default styling, then another when min-width>X.

Good luck!